# Groovy TimeCategory Mixin StackOverflowError

Tags: groovy

I tried Groovy TimeCategory Mixin according to [Groovy Coodbook](http://groovycookbook.org/basic_types/dates_times/#dates_times-UsingGroovy%27sTimeCategory)

```groovy
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

Integer.metaClass.mixin TimeCategory
Date.metaClass.mixin TimeCategory
footballPractice = 1.week.from.now - 4.days + 2.hours - 3.seconds
println footballPractice
```

It works fine in the groovy console, but I get a StackOverError, when I run it as a script

```
groovy MyScript.groovy
```

Using

- Groovy Version: 2.1.8 (via [GVM tool](http://gvmtool.net/), but the same problem with system default 1.8.x)
- JVM: 1.7.0_40 Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- OS: Linux, Ubuntu 13.04, 64bit

Comment: Works as a script for me... Is that all you have in your script?

Comment: Works for me too. /tmp$ groovy MyScript.groovy 
Thu Oct 24 01:59:57 CEST 2013

Comment: Works as a charm on same jdk, same groovy, on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, it is all. I used to have a shebang at the beginning, but it does not work even without it.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest...I can't get it to fall over...

Answer (score 0):

I will double check but I don't think mixin is recommended anymore. Try

`use(TimeCategory) {
  footballPractice = 1.week.from.now - 4.days + 2.hours - 3.seconds
  println footballPractice
}`